# In TextMate find two lines and replace with the first?

Tags: textmate

In Textmate (or with sed), how can I find two lines that start with "Date:" and replace both lines with the first?  Here's the search expression I used in TextMate that works:

```
Date+.+?$\n^Date:+.+?$
```

**Example text:**

```
blah 
blah blah 
Date: Fri,  9 Jan 2009 16:20:59 -0800 (PST) 
Date:     2009-01-09 16:20:59 -0800 (Fri, 09 Jan 2009) 
blah
```

**turn into:**

```
blah
blah blah
Date: Fri,  9 Jan 2009 16:20:59 -0800 (PST)
blah
```

Answer (score 1):

Capture the first date using parentheses:

```
(Date+.+?)$\n^Date:+.+?$
```

And then use this as your replacement field:

```
$1
```

(`$1` just means to use the text captured in the first set of parentheses in the find string.)